# Shiny - adding restrictions (e.g. character limits) to dynamically generated textInputs

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a form to get user inputs in the form of ID numbers, and the actual form filled out is dependent on user selection. I can generate they dynamic inputText boxes, but I would also like to put restrictions on the entries (for example: limit the number of characters added). Below is a sample of what I have tried, using the mtcars data set. The app runs, but text entry restrictions are not applied. The observeEvent chuck I have gotten to work on non-dynamically generated textInputs, but I can't seem to make it work in this case. I hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars2<-mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = 'CarName')


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(
      id = "car info",
      helpText("Enter a unique ID number for each car with a given number of cylinders"),
      radioButtons('cyls', 'No. of cylinders', choices = unique(mtcars2$cyl)),
      actionButton('select','Select'),
      uiOutput('textbox_ui')
    ),
  ), 
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    server = function(input, output, session){

      cyl_list <- eventReactive(input$select,{mtcars2 %>%
          filter(cyl == input$cyls) 
         })
      # Dynamically creates input text boxes based on selected FFN recipe
      textboxes<- reactive({
          lapply(seq_len(nrow(cyl_list())), function(i){
            textInput(inputId = cyl_list()[[i,'CarName']], label = cyl_list()[[i,'CarName']])
      })
    })
      output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({textboxes()})
      
      # Apply restrictions (e.g. character limit) to each dynamically created text box
      reactive({
        lapply(cyl_list()[['CarName']], function(j){
          #The portion below has worked for non-dynamically created text inputs
          observeEvent(input[[j]], {
            cat(suppressWarnings(is.na(as.numeric(input[[j]]))),'\n')
            if(nchar(input[[j]])>6){
              updateTextInput(session, paste0(j),value = '')
              showModal(modalDialog(title = 'Error!','Character limit exceeded. Inputted value outside expected range. Please try again.', easyClose = T))
            }
          })
        })
      })
      
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `reactive` to `observe` in the server.  The following works for me.

```
 server = function(input, output, session){
    
    cyl_list <- eventReactive(input$select,{
      mtcars2 %>%
        filter(cyl == input$cyls) 
    })
    # Dynamically creates input text boxes based on selected FFN recipe
    textboxes<- reactive({
      lapply(seq_len(nrow(cyl_list())), function(i){
        textInput(inputId = cyl_list()[[i,'CarName']], label = cyl_list()[[i,'CarName']])
      })
    })
    output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({textboxes()})
    
    # Apply restrictions (e.g. character limit) to each dynamically created text box
    observe({
      lapply(cyl_list()[['CarName']], function(j){
        #The portion below has worked for non-dynamically created text inputs
        observeEvent(input[[j]], {
          cat(suppressWarnings(is.na(as.numeric(input[[j]]))),'\n')
          if(nchar(input[[j]])>6){
            updateTextInput(session, paste0(j),value = '')
            showModal(modalDialog(title = 'Error!','Character limit exceeded. Inputted value outside expected range. Please try again.', easyClose = T))
          }
        })
      })
    })
    
  }
```